# str_replace not working in class file

Tags: php, html

I want replace ansi character with html entity, but it did't work.

This is my code.

My model file (save as UTF-8 encoding)

```
$this->common->htmlNamedToNumeric($orderH["@billYourref"])
```

My class file

```
function htmlNamedToNumeric($item){
    $item = str_replace('à','&agrave;',$item);
    $item = str_replace('á','&aacute;',$item);
    $item = str_replace('â','&acirc;',$item);
    $item = str_replace('ã','&atilde;',$item);
    $item = str_replace('ä','&auml;',$item);
    $item = str_replace('å','&aring;',$item);
    $item = str_replace('æ','&aelig;',$item);
    $item = str_replace('ç','&ccedil;',$item);
    $item = str_replace('è','&egrave;',$item);
    $item = str_replace('é','&eacute;',$item);
    $item = str_replace('ê','&ecirc;',$item);
    $item = str_replace('ë','&euml;',$item);
    $item = str_replace('ì','&igrave;',$item);
    $item = str_replace('í','&iacute;',$item);
    $item = str_replace('î','&icirc;',$item);
    $item = str_replace('ï','&iuml;',$item);
    $item = str_replace('ð','&eth;',$item);
    $item = str_replace('ñ','&ntilde;',$item);
    $item = str_replace('ò','&ograve;',$item);
    $item = str_replace('ó','&oacute;',$item);
    $item = str_replace('ô','&ocirc;',$item);
    $item = str_replace('õ','&otilde;',$item);
    $item = str_replace('ö','&ouml;',$item);
    $item = str_replace('×','&times;',$item);
    $item = str_replace('ø','&oslash;',$item);
    $item = str_replace('ù','&ugrave;',$item);
    $item = str_replace('ú','&uacute;',$item);
    $item = str_replace('û','&ucirc;',$item);
    $item = str_replace('ü','&uuml;',$item);
    $item = str_replace('ý','&yacute;',$item);
    return $item;
}
```

AND I've entered as $orderH["@billYourref"] as follows :

```
$orderH["@billYourref"] = 'chaussée'
```

Comment: you know [str_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) allows array for search and replace. it can convert your entire code to a single line.

Comment: you can use `htmlentities` function of php

Comment: are you sure $item have extractly ANSI code ? it not then your code can not replace correctly

Comment: @Abbas, it work, thanks for the info :)

Answer (score 0):

I've added following line to my code. It works for me.

```
function htmlNamedToNumeric($item){
    $item = htmlentities($item);
    $item = str_replace('à','&agrave;',$item);
    $item = str_replace('á','&aacute;',$item);
    $item = str_replace('â','&acirc;',$item);
    $item = str_replace('ã','&atilde;',$item);
    $item = str_replace('ä','&auml;',$item);
    $item = str_replace('å','&aring;',$item);
    $item = str_replace('æ','&aelig;',$item);
    $item = str_replace('ç','&ccedil;',$item);
    $item = str_replace('è','&egrave;',$item);
    $item = str_replace('é','&eacute;',$item);
    $item = str_replace('ê','&ecirc;',$item);
    $item = str_replace('ë','&euml;',$item);
    $item = str_replace('ì','&igrave;',$item);
    $item = str_replace('í','&iacute;',$item);
    $item = str_replace('î','&icirc;',$item);
    $item = str_replace('ï','&iuml;',$item);
    $item = str_replace('ð','&eth;',$item);
    $item = str_replace('ñ','&ntilde;',$item);
    $item = str_replace('ò','&ograve;',$item);
    $item = str_replace('ó','&oacute;',$item);
    $item = str_replace('ô','&ocirc;',$item);
    $item = str_replace('õ','&otilde;',$item);
    $item = str_replace('ö','&ouml;',$item);
    $item = str_replace('×','&times;',$item);
    $item = str_replace('ø','&oslash;',$item);
    $item = str_replace('ù','&ugrave;',$item);
    $item = str_replace('ú','&uacute;',$item);
    $item = str_replace('û','&ucirc;',$item);
    $item = str_replace('ü','&uuml;',$item);
    $item = str_replace('ý','&yacute;',$item);
    return $item;
}
```